# Can someone tell me what this piece is?

Tags: part-identification

The entire piece is 6L long and the axle portion is 4L. It has 2 pin holes perpendicular to the axle on the ends. Dark Bluish Gray.

*© Lego* printed on the side, but no part number or date. The number 5 is also printed.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [TRACK ROD 6M,etc.](https://brickset.com/parts/design-32005), which is mainly used as a steering arm in Technic cars like in this [8048-1: Buggy](https://brickset.com/sets/8048-1/Buggy).

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Just for completeness, Rebrickable and Bricklink call it a "Technic Link 1x6"